# About conjugating a $7$-cycle in a subgroup of $S_7$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Following a proof in which I have a transtive group $G$ of order $168$ , which is a subgroup of $S_7$ (I am trying to characterize it, I cannot use well know facts such as it is always isomorphic to $GL(3, 2)$). The proof claims that for every operation $\rho \in G$ of order $3$ there is an operation $\sigma \in G$ of order $7$ such that $\rho^{-1}\sigma \rho = \sigma^2$.

I was trying to prove it but I am stucked. I know that as $\rho^{-1}a^k \rho = (\rho^{-1} a \rho)^k$ for any element $a$, then the conjugation by $\rho$ must take every $7$-Sylow subgroup (cycles of order $7$) to either itself or to another $7$-Sylow. Moreover, as conjugating $3$ times is the identity, the orbits of the conjugation by $\rho$ of $7$-Sylow subgroups are either $1$ or $3$ $7$-Sylow subgroups. I already know that there are $8$ $7$-Sylow subgroups in $G$ and therefore there are at least two $7$-Sylow subgroups whose orbit is itself (the worst case is two orbits of $3$ subgroups and then two orbits of $1$ subgroup).

For those two $7$-Sylow that are mapped to itself, as conjugating $3$ times is the identity, the automorphism of the elements of a $7$-Sylow subgroup induced by the conjugations must be the exponentiation to a primitive  cubic root of unity in $\mathbb{Z}^*_7$, this is, it must be the exponentiation by $2$ or $4$. In the first case, the claim would be proved, but I don't know why that case will always happen.

Could you help me to finish my proof?

Comment: In the second case, $\rho^2$ has the required property, so it would be sufficient to prove that $\rho$ and $\rho^2$ are conjugate in $G$. Can you do that?

Comment: I knew that, but the claim was that for ANY permutation of order $3$ there is one of order $7$ such that all that. I cannot use $p^2$ to perform the conjugation

Comment: But $\rho$ is conjugate to $\rho^2$ so you are OK.

Comment: I don't see why I should be OK. I want to fix $\rho$ and then find $\sigma$, the 7-cycle. I don't see why I can obtain that using $\rho^2 $

Comment: If $\rho^2$ has the required property and $\rho^2$ is conjugate to $\rho$, then it is not hard to show that  $\rho$ has the required property too.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In my group $G$ of order $168$ I knew that every $\rho$ of order $3$ was conjugate to $\rho^2$. According to my proof, in the second case $\rho^2$ has the desired property, so for a $\sigma$ of order $7$ we have (let $\tau$ be the element of $G$ such that $\rho^2 = \tau^{-1}\rho \tau$):

$$\rho^{-2} \sigma \rho^2 = \sigma^2 \iff \tau^{-1}\rho^{-1} \tau \sigma \tau^{-1} \rho \tau = \sigma^2 \iff  \rho^{-1} \tau \sigma \tau^{-1} \rho = \tau \sigma^2 \tau^{-1} $$

And as $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}$ is a permutation of order $7$, $\rho$ also has the property.